# Keyboard doesn't show up on focus textInput - Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-softkeyboard

I use react native to make my application.

At some point, when the user clicks on an image, I automatically open a modal with a textInput inside with the props "autofocus=true".
So I want by default the keyboard to open to allow the user to write something.

However, on IOS everything works perfectly but on Android, the textInput is correctly focused (there is the bar blinking on it) but the keyboard doesn't open, I have to click on the textInput for the keyboard to decide to open !

I tried doing focus in the componentDidMount and this kind of thing, but nothing works, the android keyboard doesn't want to open automatically.

I use React-Navigation with React-Native-Screens. I saw that there were some problems with that and the keyboard not opening, but I tried the given solutions and nothing works either!

I hope someone will be able to help me to solve my problem.

Thanks

Viktor

Comment: I have the same problem using autoFocus, even using the focus() function on my ref Input...
Did you found a solution ?

Comment: I simply used a well known workaround which is to add a setTimeout on the focus! It gives a very light latency, but it does the job! I didn't find anything else, if by chance, you find one, just let me know :D

Answer (score 1):

Without ScrollView works only on ios.
Place this component around the code you need the keyboard to appear on:

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>
  // CODE
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setIsFocused(true);
  }, []);

<TextInput 
ref={(inputRef) => {
if (isFocused) {
inputRef?.focus();
setIsFocused(false);
}}}
autoFocus={true}/>
```

Comment: if blur function fires after the focus function onload, Inside useeffect function you can add like this:
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setIsFocused(true);
    }, 0);
  }, []);